# Fancybox 3.5 Ajax not working. Ajax content cannot be loaded error

Tags: jquery, fancybox

The Ajax function on Fancybox 3.5 is not working. It's bringing up a "The requested content cannot be loaded" error. The demo itself doesn't work also:

```
  <a data-fancybox data-type="ajax" data-src="https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/oBgoqB.html" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary">Open demo</a>
```

[From this pen #1](https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/yxmrWZ)

and

```
  <a data-fancybox data-type="ajax" data-src="https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/wgavbY.html" data-filter="#two" href="javascript:;">#1 Using "data-filter" attribute</a>
```

[From this pen #2](https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/jvgRRe)

Chrome developer tool error:

> VM17:1 GET https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/wgavbY.html?fancybox=true
>   503 (anonymous) @ VM17:1 send @ jquery.min.js:2 ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
>   loadSlide @ jquery.fancybox.min.js:11 jumpTo @
>   jquery.fancybox.min.js:11 init @ jquery.fancybox.min.js:11 b @
>   jquery.fancybox.min.js:11 open @ jquery.fancybox.min.js:12 i @
>   jquery.fancybox.min.js:11 dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2 y.handle @
>   jquery.min.js:2 jvgRRe:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/wgavbY.html?fancybox=true' from
>   origin 'https://s.codepen.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it sure is working very well for me, and for others, too. Since you did not provide a link to your page/project or did not share any useful details, then it is just not possible to help you.

Typical scenarios when ajax is not working:

1) You are testing on local file, opening it directly in the browser. Due to browser security policies, your file has to be served through web server;

2) Your link is incorrect;

3) Your ajax request is blocked due to `same-origin policy`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Anyway, check console output (hit F12 to open developer tools), there should be a hint about what causes your issue.

Comment: I had a feeling maybe it was just me and my computer, but I also tried it on a different laptop and still doesn't work. The only way I could make it work is by using Opera browser. Doesn't work on Chrome, Firefox and Edge. I updated my question with the Developer error on Chrome. Something about 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

Comment: Looks like codepen demos are not working for you due to CORS policy, but, trust me, fancybox works perfectly fine by itself. So, basically, you should ask codepen stuff why ajax is not working on their demos or how to create codepen demo that loads content from other demo using ajax. Also, I have no idea why it works for me and not you, maybe they are rolling different codepen versions based on user location.. I do not know...